# how to Receive UDP packets, when it comes from server? for android java

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have used a thread for UDP receive packet. When I am sending a packet to that particular IP, where the UDP receive program runs. The application will be stopped unfortunately. Then if I remove the thread called `new Thread(new Runnable())` and `public void run` the application will run good, but only one data has received. My intention is to receive data at the receiver end continuously, when data comes. please acknowledge me.

**udpserver.java:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class UdpServer extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private TextView data;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        runUdpServer();

}
private static final int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 11111;
private static final int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 1500;
private void runUdpServer() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String lText;
            byte[] lMsg = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
            DatagramSocket ds=null;
            try {
                 ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);
                //disable timeout for testing
                //ds.setSoTimeout(100000);
                ds.receive(dp);
                lText = new String(dp.getData());
                Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);
                data.setText(lText);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (ds != null) {
                    ds.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: if you want it to keep listening forever you could use a loop. `while (true) { ds.receive(dp); // more stuff  } `

Comment: Ok, thank you.. shall I use thread furthermore for this?

Comment: That depends on your program, but shouldn't hurt to keep the extra thread

Comment: @dly i am not getting the output....if i use while(true).. i have attached my code to below link  http://pdaraja.weebly.com/uploads/1/8/2/3/18237947/udpserver.txt

Comment: posted mine as answer now

Comment: whether i need to use message Handler to read the continuos data.

Comment: Replace my `LogHandler.parse()` with your `lText = ..`, `Log.i()`and `data.setText()`. Edited answer.

Comment: @dly where i need to close the socket in the program?

Comment: @dly i have attched code in the following link..nothing was happening please check out  http://pdaraja.weebly.com/uploads/1/8/2/3/18237947/new_tried.txt

Comment: try `System.out.println(lText)` at the end of the loop if there's any output

Comment: @dly i am not receiving continuously at udp receiver. hw is it possible if i am adding system.out.println(lText).

Comment: Just to check what is actually coming in. There might be other issues, but can't tell with those limited information.

Answer (score 3):

This is a working snippet I am using to receive and parse UDP packets.

```
  try {
        int port = 11000;

        DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        while (true) {

            dsocket.receive(packet);
            lText = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
            Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);
            data.setText(lText);

            packet.setLength(buffer.length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a loop to read data from the udp socket.

```
try {
    ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);
    //disable timeout for testing
    //ds.setSoTimeout(100000);
    while (!ds.isClosed()) {
        ds.receive(dp);
        lText += new String(dp.getData());
        Log.i("UDP packet received", new String(dp.getData());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data.setText(lText);
            }
        });
    }
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (ds != null) {
        ds.close();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: since the packet data is received in non-UI thread. Direct access to data.setText(lText) in worker thread is invalid.

Comment: You're ignoring the length in the datagram.

Comment: @EJP Yes, more details about buffer size or even timeout issue should be considered, but this answer only give a work sample to fix the continuous read issue.

Comment: please acknowledge me for continuos packet reception..if once socket is closed, then it will not be re-assigned.after closing of socket only i can see the incoming data..

Comment: @DineshAntonRaja you mean you want to recreate the socket and continue to receive packet when exception throws?

Comment: @jobcrazy i need to read the packet whenever it comes. But now only one time the packet has received. i think no exception throws...i have attached the code in the following website. (www.pdaraja.weebly.com)....    i have tired the while loop(true). my intention is the program should always ready to receive the packet. please acknowledge me

Comment: You should not close it until exception throws, just remove ds.close();

Comment: can you please send me the code. because if i remove ds.close() it will not show the output in textview. then i am using while(true), so how can i code. please acknowledge me..

Comment: @jobcrazy can you please send me the code. because if i remove ds.close() it will not show the output in textview. then i am using while(true), so how can i code. please acknowledge me.

Comment: @DineshAntonRaja check your code carefully plz, use !ds.isClosed() not ds.isClosed() in your while loop

Answer (score 0):

Send data and get Answer example:

```
        new Thread(()->{

            String message = "Hello Madam Coco";
            byte[] msgbyte = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            int port = 12345;
            String ip = "123,123,123,123";

            try {
                byte[] receviebyte = new byte[1024];
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                DatagramPacket sendPack = new DatagramPacket(msgbyte, msgbyte.length, address, port);
                socket.send(sendPack);
                DatagramPacket receviePack = new DatagramPacket(receviebyte, receviebyte.length);
                while (true) {

                    socket.receive(receviePack);
                    String receivestr = new String(receviebyte, receviePack.getOffset(), receviePack.getLength());
                    System.out.println("GETTEXT " + receivestr);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
      DatagramSocket clientsocket=new DatagramSocket(9876);
      byte[] receivedata = new byte[1024];
      while(true)
      {
        DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(receivedata, receivedata.length);
        Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...");
        clientsocket.receive(recv_packet);
        String rec_str = new String(recv_packet.getData());
        tv.setText(rec_str);
        Log.d(" Received String ",rec_str);
        InetAddress ipaddress = recv_packet.getAddress();
        int port = recv_packet.getPort();
        Log.d("IPAddress : ",ipaddress.toString());
        Log.d(" Port : ",Integer.toString(port));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("UDP", "S: Error", e);
    }
```

Comment: You're ignoring the length in the datagram.

Comment: the above solutions are not sufficient..only one time the packet has received..but i need the solution that, whenever the packet comes, it has to receive the packet

Comment: http://pdaraja.weebly.com/uploads/1/8/2/3/18237947/udpserver.txt                        this is the code i have used..